# ClickOnce Custom Prerequisite for SQL Server Express 2016 LocalDB?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017, clickonce, localdb, sql-server-2016-localdb

I'd like to set LocalDB 2016 as pre-requisite when publishing my WPF application. But when I check default pre-requisites in Project Properties, only one available is for SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB.

Any idea why there is no newer one, since I'm using newest possible Visual Studio 2017? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the few resources available i've found [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/3e9e48d4-ab33-4b75-95e2-2a6678ee02b9/sql-server-2016-express-localdb-bootstrapper-package-download-fails?forum=sqlexpress) by @PaulBrewer, which saved the day. Since it's easier to just download a working solution, i've uploaded my own custom MSSSQL Express LocalDB (2016) Bootstrapper/Manifest for anyone to use. Just follow instructions in readme.md:

https://github.com/igormf/SqlLocalDB2016-Bootstrapper